# count number of rows using where

Tags: mysql, sql

m new in mysql

here is my table

[image]

now i want to count "count_id" where count of 'questionID' greater than 2

Comment: It is not surprising you have many answers to choose from... if you provided "the expected result" then there is no mystery to solve. I suspect your are asking for 4 rows | count_id , CountOfID | 2 , 5 | 3 , 1 | 4 , 1 | 5 , 1 |

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT COUNT(count_id) FROM myTable WHERE questionID > 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(Count_ID),QuestionID,SurveyId from table 
where QuestionID>2
group by QuestionID,SurveyID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the statement below:

```
select count(count_id) CountOfID,count_id from mytable 
where questionID > 2 group by count_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  count(count_id) from yourtable where questionID > 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count  unique ID:

```
select count(DISTINCT count_id) from table_name where questionID > 2
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COUNT(count_id) FROM table_name WHERE questionID > 2

Answer (score 0):

Group by Count_ID and count their distinct questions. Stay with those that have more than two. Then count how many IDs you got.

```
select count(*)
from
(
  select count_id
  from mytable
  group by count_id
  having count(distinct questionid) > 2
) x;
```

EDIT: If count_id + questionid happen to be unique for the table, you can replace `count(distinct questionid)` with `count(*)`.